# Updating installed applications

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am very new on Docker. I cloned a docker image which contains python 2.7.6 pytorch 0.2. cuda version 8.0 pip version 9
I want to update python to 3.6.5 and pytorch 0.4 and pip version 18
I am using this command to run image:
nvidia-docker run -it -v /home/user:/home/user container /bin/bash
Then, I install the newest version of pip. When I exit and rerun the container pip returns to the old version(9) 
python installation gives an error.

How can I update the applications in docker image?

Comment: As I understand: You can not update them (all container changes are lost). It's a little the idea of a docker. You should make a new container with the versions you want.

Comment: Can you create a new image from the existing one? And use the new image to create a container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime you run a docker image, **nothing is persisted between docker containers** (Except volumes that you mounted).

You need to install/update the python packages of the **docker image**, not the python packages in the **docker container**.

An example of the Dockerfile in this case would be:

```
FROM <ORIGINAL IMAGE_NAME>:<VERSION>
RUN apt-get update \
  && <The manual steps you did to install/update the packages>
```

Then you would need to build the Dockerfile by running this in the Dockerfile directory:

```
docker build -t NEW_IMAGE_NAME .
```

Finally to run a **docker container** of this particular **docker image** the command would be:

```
docker run -it -v /home/user:/home/user NEW_IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash
```